# Access Document ID from a different Site Collection

Tags: feature, document-id

I have the Document ID Service feature enabled in a Site Collection. I have a Records Center site provisioned in a different Site Collection - within the same web application. If I create a document in my first site collection, and then move it to the Records Center site, will it carry the Document ID assigned to it from the first site collection?  Effectively, allowing me to search in Records Center using the document id originally assigned to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the level of each Web Application there are 2 timer jobs which calculate and assign IDs to document, as follows:

1. Document ID enable/disable job: Work item that propagates content
   type changes across all sites when the Document ID feature is
   reconfigured.
2. Document ID assignment job : Work item that assigns Document ID to
   all items in the site collection.

You would need to make sure in your Records Center the feature for Document Id is activated too. Once set by the timer job the value is maintained as you move the document, this being actually the benefit of the this feature so users are always redirected to the newest location of the exact same document as the document gets moved.

Comment: What if the document is "moved" (not copied) to a different site collection?  Meaning it would not exist in the site collection where it was originally created.  I thought I read something before that said Document ID is scoped to the site collection.

Comment: The Document Id is certainly kept across site collections (particularly if PreserveID attribute is set!) - the real issue with moving across site-collections is the duplication of Ids as the validity of the rules is applied indeed at the site collection level! - if that is not an issue for your business case then it should be fine.