# Document ID Service across site collections

Tags: document-id

I have two site collections (Document Centre and Record Centre) both with Document ID service enabled.  I have configured both to have the same Document ID prefix.  Now I use "Send To" to send a document from Document Centre to Record Centre.  Is it possible that I would get duplicate IDs in the Record Centre.

Comment: Edit: This article suggests that duplicate IDs would indeed be created http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36481/access-document-id-from-a-different-site-collection

Answer (score 0):

In fact if you use "Send to" option your document get New ID in Record Center, which can be duplicated as ID is unique at site collection level. 
Check this link http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/enable-and-configure-unique-document-ids-HA101790471.aspx for more information.